# Call a release build from REST api in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to call the Azure Devops to create a  new release from one of my Release Pipelines.

I have been looking for different calls but its either to create the pipeline or build artifacts.

Is there a way to call a release pipeline from Azure API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with the next endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1

I was using a wrong body for the endpoint. With the example from the documentation it worked.

Comment: You can accept this answer:-) Then other SO users could direct know this correct guide!